# Sending KeepAlive signals from xiff client to openfire server

Tags: actionscript-3, xmpp, openfire, xiff

I'm using xiff_3_1_0 to create an XMPP chat client connected to an openfire server.

Everything is working fine so far, except that I could not find a good way to implement the keep-alive signals correctly. There is a function named `sendKeepAlive` - in class `XMPPConnection`, but it seems that this relies on the ping-extension being supported by the server.

Actually, there is a TODO in the API documentation stating:

> Sends ping to server in order to keep the connection alive, in case
>   the server has not indicated that it would not support it. TODO:
>   Whitespace keepalive if ping not supported...

Is there an elegant way to send a whitespace keep-alive message using xiff_3_1_0?

Alternatively, is there a way to enable the ping extension on an openfire server?

Answer (score 1):

Actually you do not need to know that the server supports the ping extension ([XEP-0199](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0199.html#c2s)) before you use it. If it does not support it then the server will return an error reply, which serves just fine as a "pong".

The benefit of whitespace is that it is very lightweight, but it acts as a keep-alive rather than a ping. The best approach is to use both as necessary.

Comment: My problem is that the connection got disconnected after a few minutes despite invoking `sendKeepAlive` - I can reconnect, but would prefer not to be disconnected in the first place.